# How to write specflow scenarios that follow each other and share data?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, specflow

TLDR - Whats the best way to write specFlow scenarios that follow on from each other and share data? e.g. Scenario A - Create a user, then Scenario B login with that user (login will require the username and password specified in the create a user scenario).

Hi all,

I'm getting myself in a bit of pickle in trying to work out the best way to write a scenario for a typical register user form on a website, followed by a scenario to test the login.

I've tried creating an instance of a seperate class to store all the details of my registration form when it reaches this step (think this is context injection). e.g.

```
[Binding]
public class AdmissionsPortalFeaturesSteps : BaseStep
{
    private UserDetails userDetails;
```

The issue I'm having is the following scenario requires the password generated during the previous scenario, and I'm not able to access it with something like...

```
userDetails.Password
```

This is what I have which doesn't work currently as I want to pass the Password value from the first scenario to the second... (note if the field is set to 'random' a random value is generated in my c# code)

```
Scenario: Create a new user via the Admissions Portal
    Given I will navigate to the Admissions Portal login page
    When I click the Create an Account link
    Then I will be on the ontrack: prospect - Register page
    Given I have entered the following values on the registration page
    | fieldName                  | value  |
    | Title                      | random |
    | Firstname                  | random |
    | Middlename                 | random |
    | Surname                    | random |
    | DOB                        | random |
    | Gender                     | random |
    | EmailAddress               | random |
    | MobileNumber               | 0      |
    | Password                   | random |
    | SecurityQuestion           | random |
    | SecurityAnswer             | random |
    And I click on the Register button
    Then I will be on the Login page
        And I will get a popup confirming my registration details
    Then I close the browser window

Scenario: I am able to login to the Admissions Portal with a newly created user
    Given I will navigate to the Admissions Portal login page
        And I enter a username and password and click to login
    Then I will be on the ontrack: prospect - Home page
    Then I close the browser window
```

At the moment I see that I have the following options

1. Extend the first scenario to include the login as well and share data between steps using context injection.
2. Repeat the registration step containing the table in my login step.
3. Write a new shorter step that generates my user without the table and use this in both scenarios (I might want to later specify scenarios with specific values set in the form but concede that I might be better off ditching it).

Or something else I've not thought of...

Many thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I try to make sure that my specflow scenarios don't share any data, and if i can explicitly regenerate the whole database schema when possible  between each test.

This ensures that only data that you have arranged in the test is in the database

So I'd create a separate Given step that either runs through all the steps to create an account (you can call those steps programatically) or have a separate Given step that short circuits all that seeds the db with the information you need.

I also notice that you explicitly close your browser in your tests.  I create a  BeforeScenario/AfterScenario tag for the web that starts/stops Selenium.  So that your tests only need to test the actual functionality and not the starting/stopping of Selenium.

```
public class SeleniumController
{
    public static readonly SeleniumController Instance = new SeleniumController();
    public static readonly TimeSpan DefaultTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    public IWebDriver Selenium { get; private set; }

    private void Trace(string message) { Console.WriteLine("-> {0}", message); }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Selenium != null)
            return;

        string appUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppUrl"];

        var options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.AddArgument("test-type");
        Selenium = new ChromeDriver(options);
        Selenium.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(DefaultTimeout);

        Trace("Selenium started");
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        if (Selenium == null) return;

        try
        {
            Selenium.Quit();
            Selenium.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex, "Selenium stop error");
        }
        Selenium = null;
        Trace("Selenium stopped");
    }
}
```

scenario tags

```
public static class SeleniumSupport
{
    private static bool ReuseWebSession
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReuseWebSession"] == "true"; }
    }

    [BeforeScenario("web")]
    public static void BeforeWebScenario()
    {
        SeleniumController.Instance.Start();
    }

    [AfterScenario("web")]
    public static void AfterWebScenario()
    {
        if (!ReuseWebSession)
            SeleniumController.Instance.Stop();
    }
}
```

abstract steps base class to access selenium webdriver

```
public abstract class SeleniumStepsBase
{
    protected IWebDriver Selenium { get { return SeleniumController.Instance.Selenium; } }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Yep sounds like a good idea. Needs a bit of tidying up so will add the Before and After where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Your intention of using one scenario to set up the data for another scenario is flawed and doomed to failure IMHO.

A scenario should be totally self contained, and able to be run in isolation, not dependent on another scenario. Specflow is a unit test generation framework, but the test runner can decide on the order in which to run the tests. If you have a dependency like the one you say you want, then what happens if they don't run in order? What happens if they run in parallel? Trying to make this work will be swimming upstream, don't do it.

Instead make each scenario self contained. If you have a lot of repeated setup, put it in a background step, or create a step which calls all the other steps to do the setup, or just create a step which just does the setup you want, and then use the standard ways of sharing data between steps to manage your generated password etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Having looked a little more into this you are exactly right. I was trying to setup my data in one scenario, then use that data in all the other scenarios. As you pointed out if the tests were run out of order they would fall over. I've decided to keep my specific register a user scenario, then have a shorter version 'Given I have created a user' which calls all the steps from the register a user scenario. I then use that as setup for my other scenarios. Test execution time is longer as I am creating a user each time but the tests are now fully independent.

Answer (score 0):

I use  FeatureContext.Current or ScenarioContext.Current to store information that i pass between scenarios or features. FeatureContext is a Specflow global dictionary and that can be accessed anywhere. [Specflow FeatureContext](http://specflow.org/documentation/FeatureContext/)

```
FeatureContext.Current["username"] = "someUsername";
```

Or

```
ScenarioContext.Current["username"] = "someUsername";
```

Comment: I would avoid this method of sharing data, as it won't work in a parallel scenario without injecting the contexts into your step classes, and I think it is going to be deprecated in some future version